# Bitmap image coming out warped

Tags: java, arrays, bitmap, rgb

```
// load pixels into an image
        this.image = new BufferedImage(this.width,
                                       this.height, 
                                       BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // get actual image data for easier pixel loading
        byte[] iData = new byte[this.size - 54];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.size - 54; i++) {
            iData[i] = this.data[i+54];
        }

        // start from bottom row
        for(int y = this.height-1; y >= 0; y--) {
            for(int x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
                int index = (this.width*y + x) * 3;
                int b = iData[index];
                int g = iData[index+1];
                int r = iData[index+2];

                //System.out.format("R: %s\nG: %s\nB: %s\n\n", r, g, b);

                // merge rgb values to single int
                int rgb = ((r&0x0ff)<<16)|((g&0x0ff)<<8)|(b&0x0ff); 

                // build image from bottom up
                this.image.setRGB(x, this.height-1-y, rgb);
            }
        }
```

I'm reading RGB values from a Bitmap. My iData byte array is correct, as I've checked it against a hex editor. However, when I run this loop, my output image is warped (see picture). I've been wracking my brain for hours trying to fix this, why is it happening?

Input image is a canadian flag.

output image:

[image: warped canada flag]

Comment: Does your input file have 4-byte-aligned rows? Some formats add padding to the end of each line to make each row a multiple of 4 bytes long.

Comment: Because you're probably not accounting for that.

Comment: @Tetramputechture It means you need to use a different value to multiply y by.

Comment: You're all right, and I've solved it. This all stemmed from when I thought I didn't need that adjusted width, so I removed it from the loop, but my debugging method was incorrect, so I didn't see the results. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't accounting for the zero-byte padding on the width, for which the formula is

WidthWithPadding = ceiling((w*colorDepth)/32)*32.

Answer (score 0):

Images usually have width, depth (bits per pixel), and stride. Usually the stride is not just width*depth, but padded by some amount (often used to align each row to a 16-bit boundary for memory access reasons).

Your code does not appear to be accounting for the stride or any padding, which explains the offset as you go through the image. I'm surprised the colors don't get switched (suggesting the padding is the same size as a pixel), but those undefined values are causing the black stripe through the image.

Rather than multiplying `(this.width*y + x) * 3` to get your index, you should use `(this.stride*y + x) * 3` with the appropriate value for stride. The [BufferedImage class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) doesn't seem to provide that in any obvious fashion, so you need to calculate or fetch that otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The general issue that's happening is that your code has conflated stride (distance between rows in bytes) with width (number of bytes in a row); in aligned data formats these are not necessarily the same thing.  The general result of this is getting the sort of skew you're seeing, as the second row starts out on the last byte(s) of the first row, the third row starts out on the second-to-last byte(s) of the second row, and so on.

The first thing you need to do is calculate the stride of the data, and use that as the multiplication factor for the row.  Here is a simplified loop that also is somewhat more efficient than multiplying on a per-pixel basis:

```
int stride = (this.width + 3) & ~3; // rounds up to the nearest multiple of 4
for (int y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
    int idx = y*stride;
    for (int x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
        int b = iData[idx++];
        int g = iData[idx++];
        int a = iData[idx++];
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Note that the rounding trick above (`(w + a - 1) & ~(a - 1)`) only works for power-of-two values; a more general form of the rounding trick is:

```
int stride = (width + stride - 1)/stride*stride;
```

although it's very uncommon to find alignments that aren't a power of 2 in the first place.